# JS Cypress: unable to use alias for array

Tags: cypress, alias, cypress-after-hook

I am quite new to Cypress and I have some `before()` calling commands that create bunch of things via API calls and return the IDs of created which I  use in the `after()` for removing them, but somehow it works perfectly if I only return one ID and store in the alias but will fail if I store an array of IDs in alias, is this intended or I did something wrong.

in my code:

```js
before(() => {
  cy.setupEnv()
    .as('access_token')
    .then((token) => cy.setupFlow(token).as('data_id'))
})

after(function () {
  console.log(this.access_token)
  console.log(this.data_id)
})
```

`console.log(this.data_id)` shows fine if setupFlow returns only one ID but becomes undefined if I try to `return [id1,id2,id3]`and store the array using `.as("data_id")`

Comment: What does this produce `cy.setupFlow(token).as('data_id')` just one id or array of id's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've struck a strange issue, worth raising with Cypress.

It only seems to happen if you have ***more than one test***.

For example, if I run the following it logs the array.

```js
before(() => {
  cy.wrap(1).as('access_token')
  cy.then(() => {
    return [1,2,3]
  }).as('data_id')
})

after(function () {
  console.log(this.access_token)            // 1
  console.log(this.data_id)                 // [1,2,3]
})

it('test1', () => {
  console.log('test1')
  expect(true).to.eq(true)
})
```

If I add a test it logs undefined!

```js
before(() => {
  cy.wrap(1).as('access_token')
  cy.then(() => {
    return [1,2,3]
  }).as('data_id')
})

after(function () {
  console.log(this.access_token)            // 1
  console.log(this.data_id)                 // undefined
})

it('test1', () => {
  console.log('test1')
  expect(true).to.eq(true)
})

it('test2', () => {
  console.log('test2')
  expect(true).to.eq(true)
})
```

One way around this is to use `Cypress.env()` instead

```js
before(() => {
  cy.wrap(1).as('access_token')
  cy.then(() => {
    Cypress.env('data_id', [1,2,3])
    return [1,2,3]
  }).as('data_id')
  console.log('before')
})

after(function () {
  console.log(this.access_token)            // 1
  console.log(this.data_id)                 // undefined
  console.log(Cypress.env('data_id'))       // [1,2,3]
})

beforeEach(function() {
  console.log(cy.state())
  console.log(this.data_id)
  cy.wrap(this.data_id).as('data_id')
})

it('test1', () => {
  expect(true).to.eq(true)
  console.log('test1')
})

it('test2', () => {
  console.log('test2')
  expect(true).to.eq(true)
})
```

Comment: oh wow, that's exactly what I have right now! I removed one of the tests and now I'm able to get the full array returned to me! I'm surprised you could reproduce, I have been scratching my head for the entire night.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get my head around it - something to do with the alias cleardown between tests, but I thought that `this.data_id` was not cleared. Perhaps it's a recent change that does it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `cy.setupFlow(token)` generates an array of values something like `[id1, id2, id3]`. This will work even when there is one value in the array. You after each should look this:

```js
after(function () {
  cy.get('@data_id').then((data_id) => {
    //Get individual values
    cy.log(data_id[0])
    cy.log(data_id[1])
    cy.log(data_id[2])

    //Get all values using forEach
    data_id.forEach((id) => {
      cy.log(id) //get all values one by one
    })
  })
})
```

I created a small POC for this and it is working as expected.Below are the results.

**Code:**

```js
describe('SO Ques', () => {
  before(function () {
    cy.wrap([1, 2, 3]).as('array')
  })

  it('SO Ques', function () {
    cy.log('Hello')
  })

  after(function () {
    cy.get('@array').then((array) => {
      cy.log(array[0])
      cy.log(array[1])
      cy.log(array[2])
    })
  })
})
```

**Result:**

[image: Test Runner screenshot]